# UIPageViewController phase

Tags: swift

I read that :

To create the page content view controller, we add a helper method.
In this method, at a certain point, there's this line :

```
if let pageContentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as? PageContentViewController { ....`                                                      }                   `
```

My question is :

Why previously "**storyboard**" isn't been declared, but appeares now in the above line ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes to make a project easier, the project is built across various storyboards.

If you just have one storyboard, you know that to access other view controller on this only one storyboard, you'd say:

```
self?.instantiateViewController....
// Here self refers to itself.. the only storyboard you havve
```

In your code, however, an attempt is being made to access a view controller across a different storyBoard. This different storyboard would have an id (which you set in activity inspector)

```
//This is how you access a view controller in a different storyboard
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "yourStoryBoardID", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourViewControllerID") as UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This link : "http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/organizing-xcode-projects-using-multiple-storyboards" is extremely helpful in providing reference to multiple storyboards.

To make it clear: It is nothing to do with page view controller, it is because we are using multiple storyboards.
Also, it would be better if you could provide more code or references.

Comment: Akshansh Thakur right that's the point.  In your code, you firstly created the instance " storyboard " and then use it.  Instead, across that I'm reading there isn't a declaration to the istance storyboard, but being only used.  Why ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of where you see it? @Shar3r

Comment: I think they just used storyboard assuming you know how to declare it. They probably didnt use self, because that might have caused confusion as to what class's instance is it. Also, by naming it storyboard, they made a point that multiple storyboards can be accessed from any View Controller

Comment: can you post the screenshot of it or give me an online link? I dont have the book :(

Comment: Thakur the code is right identical to my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `storyboard?` variable should be an instance of the UIStoryboard where you have your `PageContentViewController`. The above code of Akshansh Thakur shows you how to create a UIStoryboard, use it.

It isn't be declared because I think it was enough clear to understand how to create the `PageContentViewController` . Whatever, create the `storyboard` variable just above your line of code

`if let pageContentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as? PageContentViewController { ....`                                                      }